# how tensorflow deals with np.nan?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nan

Please consider the following code,

```
x = tf.constant([[[1, np.nan, np.nan], [4, 3, -1]], [[10, np.nan, 3], [20,5,-7]], [[5, np.nan, 3], [np.nan,15,-17]]])
x_max = tf.reduce_max(x, reduction_indices=[0])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (np.shape(sess.run(x)))
    print (sess.run(x))
    print (sess.run(x_max))
```

The output is as following:

```
(3, 2, 3)
[[[  1.  nan  nan]
  [  4.   3.  -1.]]

 [[ 10.  nan   3.]
  [ 20.   5.  -7.]]

 [[  5.  nan   3.]
  [ nan  15. -17.]]]
[[ 10. -inf   3.]
 [ 20.  15.  -1.]]
```

Now my question is how tensorflow deals with *np.nan*, like *numpy.nanmax* or similar?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2013

Answer (score 0):

Quoting this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2013) (credit goes to [Yaroslav Bulatov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419116/yaroslav-bulatov)):

> Different parts of TensorFlow treat them differently:
>   * Float computations (usually?) propagate them.
>   * Int conversion treats them as 0.
>   * Int computations fail with Python parts of TensorFlow often raise an error on "NaN", ie, trying to add a NaN summary to histogram will fail with Python
>   exception.

Here is an example for some float operations:

```
a = tf.constant([1.0, np.nan])
b = tf.constant(np.nan)
r = tf.reduce_min(a)
m = a * b
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(r)) # prints 1.0
    print(sess.run(m)) # array([nan, nan], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: So in float computations, e.f. with tf.reduce_min it will propagate! like numpy.nanmax? if I understood correctly?

Comment: Actually `tf.reduce_min` does not propagate them. See my edited answer.

Comment: what is _m = a B v_! again when you print _r_, it prints _1.0_ that means it ignores _np.nan_!

Comment: Sorry, `m = a*b`